# Featherlight Gallery Livefilter

Tags: javascript, featherlight.js

I have a gallery with a huge amount of images so the user can filter the images by category. When the user hides a category (clicks on a filter) and then click on the image to start the gallery, all images (even the hidden ones) shows in the diashow.

```
$('.gallery a').featherlightGallery({
  'type': 'image'
});

$('#toggle-group-a').click(function(){
   $('.group-a').toggle(); 
});

$('#toggle-group-b').click(function(){
   $('.group-b').toggle(); 
});

$('#toggle-group-c').click(function(){
   $('.group-c').toggle(); 
});
```

Standalone-Example at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xap78z34/6/

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind featherlight to your wrapper (`'.gallery'`?) and use the `filter` option, (probably `a:visible`).

Comment: Shame on me. That was too easy. Thank you so much!